# Do a row count in all tables in a DB where columnA=1 and columnB=DEV

Tags: netezza

I need to do a row count on a Netezza system but only where 2 columns have certain values

I have

```
SELECT TABLENAME, RELTUPLES 
FROM _V_TABLE 
WHERE objtype = 'TABLE' and tablename like 'MY%STUFF'
```

This will show me all table names and their row counts

But I need to add a where clause into it.  columnA= 1 and columnB = ABC,

every table has these 2 column names in it.

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via SQL, then you can accomplish this with a stored procedure. Here's a stored procedure that will do what I think you're asking for.

My assumption is that you want to only count the rows in tables that actually match the column values specified, so RELTUPLES in _v_tables won't be of use for that.  The sample stored procedure code also assumes that each of the columns is varchar(1000).  You'll have to alter the code if you want to match other datatypes.

Prior to creating the stored procedure, create a reference table like so:

```
create table reftable_sp_row_count (tablename varchar(1000), rowcount bigint) distribute on random;
```

Then create the stored procedure like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_ROW_COUNT(VARCHAR(254), VARCHAR(254), VARCHAR(254), VARCHAR(254), VARCHAR(254))
RETURNS REFTABLE(REFTABLE_SP_ROW_COUNT)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    pTablePattern ALIAS FOR $1;
    pColOneName ALIAS FOR $2;
    pColOneValue ALIAS FOR $3;
    pColTwoName ALIAS FOR $4;
    pcolTwoValue ALIAS FOR $5;

    vRecord RECORD;
BEGIN

for vRecord in 
EXECUTE 'SELECT schema
      || ''.''
      || tablename tablename
FROM _v_table v
WHERE tablename LIKE ''' || upper(pTablePattern) || '''
AND EXISTS
   (
      SELECT attname
      FROM _v_relation_column c
      WHERE c.objid = v.objid
      AND attname   = ''' || upper(pColOneName) || '''
   )
AND EXISTS
   (
      SELECT attname
      FROM _v_relation_column c
      WHERE c.objid = v.objid
      AND attname   = ''' || upper(pColTwoName) || '''
   )'
   LOOP

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || REFTABLENAME || 
   ' SELECT '''  ||  vRecord.tablename || ''' , COUNT(1) from ' || vRecord.tablename || 
   ' where ' || upper(pColOneName) || ' = ''' || pColOneValue || ''' and ' || upper(pColTwoName) || ' = ''' || pColTwoValue || ''' ;';

   -- Note that if you change the data types for a given column to a different type then you'll want to change ''' || pColOneValue || ''' to ' || pColOneValue || '  as appropriate
   END LOOP;

RETURN REFTABLE;
END;
END_PROC;
```

Here is some sample output.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from table_1 order by colA, colB;
 COLA | COLB
------+------
 ABC  | BLUE
 ABC  | BLUE
 ABC  | BLUE
 ABC  | RED
 ABC  | RED
(5 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from table_2 order by colA, colB;
 COLA |  COLB
------+--------
 ABC  | BLUE
 ABC  | BLUE
 XYZ  | BLUE
 XYZ  | BLUE
 XYZ  | YELLOW
(5 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> call sp_row_count('TABLE_%', 'COLA', 'ABC', 'COLB','BLUE');
   TABLENAME   | ROWCOUNT
---------------+----------
 ADMIN.TABLE_1 |        3
 ADMIN.TABLE_2 |        2
(2 rows)
```